# Indentation and Formatting of SQL code in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to indent code as follow:

```
SELECT e.employee_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT e.departmetn_id) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY e.manager_id)
  FROM employees e
 WHERE e.employee_id in (100, 110, 150)
   AND e.department_id = 50
    OR e.employee_id not in (100, 110, 150)
 ORDER BY e.employee_id
```

I'll have an easy life if i could have a space column between my select, from and where (like a right margin) and the rest of the statement. It feels clearer to me. I'm actually trying with <kbd>Ctrl + F7</kbd> but the result is not that eye catching for me:

```
SELECT e.employee_id,
        COUNT (DISTINCT
              e.departmetn_id
       ) OVER (PARTITION BY
              e.manager_id
       )
FROM employees e
WHERE
              e.employee_id IN (
                     100,110,150
              )
       AND
              e.department_id = 50
       OR
              e.employee_id NOT IN (
                     100,110,150
              )
ORDER BY e.employee_id;
```

I hope to be as clear as possible. If the <kbd>Ctrl + F7</kbd> way is the standard I'll just try to get used to it.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

I took your code - and formatted is using the right align keywords option.

Before -

[image]

After - with preference indicated (you need a recent version, we added this sometime in the version 18.x timeline)

[image]

Or here's the formatted text

```
SELECT e.employee_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT e.departmetn_id) OVER(
              PARTITION BY e.manager_id
       )
  FROM employees e
 WHERE e.employee_id IN (
       100,
       110,
       150
)
   AND e.department_id = 50
    OR e.employee_id NOT IN (
       100,
       110,
       150
)
 ORDER BY e.employee_id;
```

We keep the keyword alignment on the first keyword, so the 'ORDER' not the 'BY' on an ORDER or GROUP.